# Adherent Points vs. Limits of Sequences

Tags: general-topology, limits

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A$ a subset. An **adherent point** of $A$ is a point $p$ such that any open set containing $p$ intersects $A$ nontrivially.

My question is: If $p$ is an adherent point of $A$, is necessarily the limit of some sequence of points in $A$?

A brief (failed) attempt at a proof leads me to believe that a clever counterexample probably exists. The statement is true for first-countable topological spaces (in particular, for all metric spaces), so that narrows the search space somewhat. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it’s not true in general; here’s one of the simpler Hausdorff counterexamples. Let $X$ be an uncountable set, fix a point $p\in X$, and let

$$\tau=\wp(X\setminus\{p\})\cup\{U\subseteq X:p\in U\text{ and }X\setminus U\text{ is countable}\}\;;$$

$\tau$ is a Hausdorff topology on $X$. Let $A=X\setminus\{p\}$; then $p\in\operatorname{cl}A$, but no sequence in $A$ converges to $p$. To see that, note that if $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $A$, then $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is countable, so $X\setminus\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an open nbhd of $p$ that contains no term of the sequence.

Comment: thaks a lot prof scott

Comment: @ILoveMath: You're very welcome.